# "either is fine" and "both are fine"

Tags: phrases

When asked for preference between two things, e.g. today or tomorrow?

I feel like "either is fine" is dominant among native speakers. What about "both are fine"? Somehow I'm more inclined to say the latter, but not sure of its legitimacy.

Clarifications:
The exact question is like this: Shall we go today or tomorrow? Meaning to choose only one of the two.

The definition of both is "to refer to two things", example is "both his parents indulged him". Follow this logic I can describe a common property of two things by saying "both days are fine". Right? I sense this is the logic of my language faculty when producing the answer.

Comment: "Either" implies one or the other.  "Both", in the context which you suggest (but alas do not explicitly provide) implies that it could be one, the other, or both.  But "both" could confuse the listener into believing that the option you desire is to have both simultaneously.

Comment: Dictionary, dictionary, dictionary. *Either* => or. *Both* => and. And *fine* is extraneous to your problem understanding, here. Please start with a dictionary or some other research. Google works: *either definition*, *both definition*.

Answer (score 4):

As the comments state, there are differences.  One would not say "Both are fine" if asked about travel on Saturday or Sunday, if one cannot travel on both days.

If the question is "Would you like chocolate or vanilla ice cream", the answer might be "either", meaning get one, or "both" meaning get both.